# Google Fusion Tables Future?

Tags: google-fusion-tables

Does anyone (from Google) know when and if Google Fusion Tables will become "fully" supported instead of being marked as an "experimental application" as stated at:

[Google Fusion Tables page](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/)

We would like to make use of Fusion Tables for a project, but before committing time and resources, it would be nice to know that Fusion Tables will be around moving forward.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not customer support for Google. This should be addressed to them.

Comment: Honestly, we aren't, but customer support used to officially ask users to post here, with fusion-tables tag.
Needless to say that none of them ever replied :)
I'd rather close it since we have an ultimate answer ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They will die on December 2019.

See https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/9185417

> **Notice: Google Fusion Tables Turndown**
>
> Last updated: December 11, 2018
>
> Google Fusion Tables and the Fusion Tables API will be turned down December 3, 2019. Embedded Fusion Tables visualizations — maps, charts, tables and cards — will also stop working that day. Maps using the Fusion Tables Layer in the Maps JavaScript API v3.37 will start to see errors in August 2019.
>
> (remainder snipped)

And also https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-fusion-tables/HMqJLkyGDHw

> **Google Fusion Tables to be
>   shut down on December 3, 2019**
>
> Google Fusion Tables was launched almost nine years ago (snip)
>   For a long time, it was one of the few free tools for easily
>   visualizing large datasets, especially on a map. Since then, Google
>   has developed several alternatives (snip).
>
> In order to continue focusing our efforts in these areas, we will be
>   retiring Fusion Tables. We plan to turn down Fusion Tables and the
>   Fusion Tables API on December 3, 2019. Embedded Fusion Tables
>   visualizations — maps, charts, tables and cards — will also stop
>   working that day. Maps using the Fusion Tables Layer in the Maps
>   JavaScript API v3.37 will start to see errors in August 2019.
>
> Please visit the [Help Center](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/9185417?vid=0-1524208232962-1544546853550) to learn about next steps, including how
>   to download your data and information on alternative tools.
>
> (remainder snipped)

Answer (score 0):

it is unclear, but they have updated to api v2 so I imagine it has a future, but like any google project (especially experimental status) this can quickly be revoked it seems!